# How to find valid IP addresses of a network /16

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, subnet

I have this network address: **157.67.0.0 /16**

And I have to identify the valid IP Addresses for the network:

**a) 157.67.171.96**

b) 157.67.177.69

c) 157.67.172.154

**d) 157.67.180.32**

e) 157.67.246.95

I already know which ones are correct but I don't know why **(Correct A and D)** (At least this is what my teacher said)

Can anyone explain what makes those two valid and the rest of the answers invalid?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains how to figure that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with your example, according the question all of the addresses are valid for the network.

`/16` at the end of the network address means that the first 16 bits of address represent the network address and the last 16 are used for host address. You can see your address binary representation [here](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=157.67.0.0&mask1=16&mask2=)